# Why do I see these messages while updating Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager, update-notifier

LC MESSAGES 
LC TYPE 
LC ALL
as Default locale :No such file or directory.

Please let me know how to correct this?

Comment: Is the language of your OS English?

Comment: Yes I did select language as English US

Comment: @SHK did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then reboot. It must solve your problem.

Comment: I did download something and I didn't see such messages and I believe it has worked but I used to see them when I whenever updated. I will inform you on next update possibly by next Monday when I will return. But I am thankful for the solution.

Comment: Today I have updated and again found the message not sure why but I have ran your recommended command again.

Comment: I am seeing below messages

Comment: I am seeing below messages as              perl:warning : please check that your locale settings :

LANGUAGE =(unset), LC_ALL=(unset), LANG="EN_IN.ISO8859-1" are supported and installed on your system. Perl:warning :Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). Then I see the same messages LC MESSAGES LC TYPE LC ALL as Default locale :No such file or directory. Please suggest.